# Absorption's Law - Negative proposition affects the law?

Tags: propositional-calculus

This is a simple question.

It's known that the absorption's law is like the following example:

> p ∧ (p V q) = p

But, if the proposition has a negation, does this affect the law?
for example:

> p ∧ **¬(p V q)** = p

Is this correct?

**Edit:** Is the De Morgan's Law necessary before the Absorption's Law?

Comment: Negation like that does affect the law: your example does not hold.

Comment: Hi @Berci, I've just edit the post with a new question, is that what you mean?

Comment: Use turh table to check them... In the second case, with both $p,q$ TRUE the RHS is True while the LHS is False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De Morgan's Law helps to show that no absorption law holds for your example.

(p ∧ ¬(p V q)) = (p ∧ (¬p ∧ ¬q))

By association we then can get

((p ∧ ¬p) ∧ ¬q)

But, (p ∧ ¬p) is always false, so (p ∧ ¬(p V q)) is always false also.

p can be true or false, and thus no absorption law holds for your example involving negation.